# Auto-Start Virtual Machines from Hyper-V Manager (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012, automation, schedule

My company has 2 server; one is main server and another one is accounting server. At first, both servers use Windows Server 2008 then I upgraded main server OS to Windows Server 2012 and everything works fine. Later, I upgraded an accounting server to Windows Server 2012 but my program on accounting server does not compatible with this new version of Windows Server. So, I used Hyper-V and simulate everything on my accounting server for using as Virtual Machine on my new accounting server with Windows Server 2012. Here is my problem, according to company policy, both servers must be shutdown every Sunday and re-open on Monday morning. All services on main server can be started automatically --> no problem. But problem is on accounting server that Hyper-V can be started automatically but my accounting Virtual Machine cannot! I must start my accounting server (VM) manually every Monday. "Is there any way, tool to handle this scenario?" Please help ...

Best Regards,
Jeff Tuampi

Answer (score 1):

You simply should configure your virtual machine to *"Always start automatically"* - as soon as the host and the Hyper-V services start up, the virtual machine will be started too:

[image: hyper-v start-up properties]

Comment: Oh my god, you saved my life ,.,,, Thank you very much !

Comment: @JeffTuampi this was an easy save. I should consider a career in rescue, if it is all that easy.

Comment: I am not sure that it's my mistake or not, but today after server was restarted but my virtual machine cannot be started as I following your suggestion. Is there anything that i must change or not? Please help ... T__T